# How many solutions does this sytem of equations have?

Tags: systems-of-equations

Let $a, y \in \mathbb{R}^+$ with $y<a$, and $b, x \in [0, \pi/2]$.  Now consider the system of two equations given by

\begin{align}
a &= \frac{1}{\tan(x)} + y\\
b & = (x+y) \mod \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}

where mod with real numbers is defined in the natural way.  Now, for fixed, known values $a, b$, I am supposed to determine if there exist an uncountably infinite, countably infinite, or finite set of $x, y$ pairs that satisfy the system of equations.  Would anyone happen to know how to go about doing this, saying how they arrived at the answer they did?  Thanks!

Comment: Notice that if you change $x$ by an integer multiple of $\pi$, then neither right side changes.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed, however we have the requirement that $x \in [0, \pi/2]$

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that.

Comment: It seems that there is always one solution - the tan part provides a continuous vertical not line (the tan shape) and a line segment crossing it.

Comment: @Moti  that is what I noticed too, however I am not sure if the mod allows for more than one solution, because you can rewrite the mod part as $b=(x+y)c+\pi/2 d$ where c and d are integer parameters for this line, so you can obtain multiple intersection points.

Comment: You are right. There are parallel lines separated by $pi/2$